# PyGame и Анаконда

Tags: python, windows-10, pygame, anaconda

Какая версия PyGame подойдет для установки на Анаконду 3 v5.1.0 на OS Windows 10?
Как лучше устанавливать PyGame? Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты с pip, с командами в jupyter notebook и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip3 install pygal
```

сработало в моем случае: Windows 10, Anaconda 3.5.x, Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 install pygame
conda install pygame
python3 -m pip install pygame
```